# No adjective ending on "panzerartig" in Kafka's The Metamorphosis

Tags: adjective, declension

He writes

> "Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken"

and I'm confused as to why "hart" gets inflected but "panzerartig" doesn't. The full sentence, if it has any bearing, is:

> "Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken und sah, wenn er den Kopf ein wenig hob, seinen gewölbten, braunen, von bogenförmigen Versteifungen geteilten Bauch, auf dessen Höhe sich die Bettdecke, zum gänzlichen Niedergleiten bereit, kaum noch erhalten konnte."

Comment: No reason to downvote a duplicate. A close vote will do.

Comment: @infinitezero Did you read the tooltip text when hovering the DV button? And not to mention check out [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agerman.stackexchange.com+inflection+artig+adjective&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&oq=site%3Ager&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i59j69i58.17819j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) please. What do you see as the 1st hit? Also upvotes aren't meant to counter downvotes for no reason.

Comment: There is no tool tip for me on either button. But I suppose it might promise you cookies if you click it.

Comment: @infinitezero However. It says: _"**This question does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful."_